# Force Calculate using UIAcceleration values in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to calculate force value of iphone using UIAcceleration values....

Can anyone help me?

What i want is ? When user moves slowly from one region  to other  i want to do some task  or they move faster i want to do some other task ....

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: The accelerometer returns acceleration, rather than speed, so you will need to measure the vector of acceleration over the three axis, subtract the constant of gravity, and what you have left is your phone acceleration. If you know the orientation of the phone, this is quite easy: if you can force it to be flat then you just ignore one vector if you don't, then its much harder!

Answer (score 0):

force creates acceleration. if you're really looking for force, you need to account for the mass of the iphone. but I'm just being pedantic here :)

so you want to accomplish different actions based on the acceleration?

what you'll need to do is register yourself as a delegate of UIAccelerator. whenever didAccelerate fires off, it'll give you the [x,y,z] and the timestamp of the event.

so if you care about the X direction, the x property will have the acceleration in gravities (i.e. 1 = 9.8 meters per seconds squared).

you'll need gyroscopes for any more (orientation, etc).

source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html